# Eclipse IDE(LPC-Link2) デバッグの実行でエラーになる

Tags: eclipse, spresense

Eclipse IDE(LPC-Link2) デバッグの実行でエラーとなる。

Eclipse デバックの実行でLPC-Link2のCMSIS-DAPを認識後、タイムアウトでエラーが出てしまいます。

後一歩の気がするのですが、かれこれ1ヶ月ほど悩んでおります。

○ IDEは２つ試しましたが結果は同じでした
　①Eclipse 2019.03 + macOS 10.14.5 (Mojave)
　②Eclipse 2019.03 + Ubuntu 16.04

○ Eclipseのコンソールとエラー内容

```
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
cortex_m reset_config sysresetreq
Started by GNU MCU Eclipse
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : CMSIS-DAP: SWD  Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: JTAG Supported
Info : CMSIS-DAP: FW Version = 1.10
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface Initialised (SWD)
Info : SWCLK/TCK = 1 SWDIO/TMS = 1 TDI = 1 TDO = 1 nTRST = 0 nRESET = 1
Info : CMSIS-DAP: Interface ready
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
```

↑ここで
　下記のエラーがダイヤログに表示される

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
Failed to execute MI command:
-target-select remote localhost:3333
Error message from debugger back end:
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
localhost:3333: Operation timed out.
```

○ LPC-Link2
・FirmwareはLPCScrypt v2.1.0で書込み
　(lpcscrypt_2.1.0_842/scripts/program_CMSIS を実行)
・lsusbの結果
　Bus 020 Device 006: ID 1fc9:0090 NXP Semiconductors LPC-LINK2 CMSIS-DAP V5.224  Serial: I3FWBSKS
・JP1 Close(緑丸印)
・JP2 Open(青丸印)

○Spresense
・シリアルコンソールでデバッグ待ちを確認しました
　Waiting for debugger connection..
・Firmware 1.3.0
・SWDコネクタ　KEY(NC)ピンは切断し接続しない状態にしてあります

宜しくお願い致します

[image: 接続]
[image: Eclipse画面]
[image: 実行－メイン]
[image: 実行－デバッグ]
[image: 実行－Start]

Answer (score 0):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。

お問い合わせいただきましたICE（LPC-Link2）と接続できない件ですが、
こちらで改めて確認しましたが、Eclipse上でSPRESENSEのデバッグが
問題なく動作しております。

■環境
　Spresense SDK：v1.4.0
　LPC-Link2のfirmware version：1.10
　Eclipse version: Eclipse 2019-03 (4.11)

一方、以下のケースではご指摘内容と同じエラーメッセージが発生することが見えています。

- SWDの接続ケーブルでICE（LPC-Link2）とSPRESENSE拡張ボードを接続していない。
- SPRESENSE拡張ボード基板へのSWDコネクタのはんだ付けが不良。

このことから、以下の点をご確認ください。

1. SWDの接続ケーブルに断線などがないか
2. SWDコネクタのはんだ付けに不具合がないか

また、リリースされましたv1.4.0ではVS CodeのIDE環境が提供されており、
ICEでのデバッグが可能になっています。詳細は以下のページをご参照ください。

[Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html)

今後ともSPRESENSEをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
SPRESENSEサポートチーム

Comment: やはり LPC-Link2だとつながらないです。

■環境
　Spresense SDK：v1.5.1
　LPC-Lin2 インストーラー：LPCScrypt_2.1.1_15 → CMSIS-DAP V5.361

■一方、ARM-Keil ULIN2(正規品)で繋がることを確認できました

Answer (score 0):

[Spresense SDK スタートガイド (IDE 版)](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html)

には「ARM-Keil ULINK2(正規品)」と「LPC-Link2」が紹介されてますが、
下記のものも、一応繋がる様です

PARTICLE DEBUGGER
　Particle Industries, Inc.

Digi-Keyあたりで買えそうです

SonyさんVS Codeで開発できる Spresense SDKを紹介してた時に、似た様なものを使ってましたよね
(去年の2019年8月頃。9月頃に正式版が出る予定とか言ってた時に見ました)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]